# Turning negative Price amounts to positive

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have to write a small generic conversion in XSL 1.0 that turns the negative prices in to positive when the Book Name concerns a 'NC'. Prices can occur at multiple/any levels. I have to encounter negative sign and turn that to positive for any kind of XML. Please suggest.

XML-

```
<Books>
 <Book>
  <Name>NC</Name>
  <Price>-100.50</Price>
 </Book>
 <Book>
  <Name>B1</Name>
  <Pr>450.60</Pr>
 </Book>
 <Book>
  <Name>C1</Name>
  <Price>35.20</Price>
 </Book>
 <Book>
  <Name>D1</Name>
  <P>5</P>
 </Book>
</Books>
```

Comment: Please show [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to the text Price elements with a number less than zero, that belong to Book elements with a Name of 'NC'. In this case, you just need the following template match

```
<xsl:template match="Book[Name='NC']/Price[number(.) &lt; 0]/text()">
```

Then you can just add code to turn the negative value to positive.

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Book[Name='NC']/Price[number(.) &lt; 0]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(0 - number(.), '0.00')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<Books>
   <Book>
      <Name>NC</Name>
      <Price>100.50</Price>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <Name>B1</Name>
      <Pr>450.60</Pr>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <Name>C1</Name>
      <Price>35.20</Price>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <Name>D1</Name>
      <P>5</P>
   </Book>
</Books>
```

Note the use of the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy existing elements.